# How to get the jquery variable from one php file into another?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to pass a jquery variable from one PHP file to another.

for this, I am posting the variable into the server using ajax in page1.php and getting the variable from the server using PHP in page2.php

In page1.php,

```
$.ajax({
      url: "page2.php",
      type: "POST",
      data:{"myDat":activeCount}
}).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
});
```

In page2.php,

```
<?php 
     $data1 = isset($_REQUEST['myDat'])?$_REQUEST['myDat']:"";
     echo $data1;
?>
```

I am getting the ajax code (console.log(data)) get printed on the console.

But I am not getting the data in PHP (echo $data1)

Can anyone please help?

Comment: use `$_POST`, not `$_REQUEST`. and `var_dump($_POST); exit` on your PHP script so you can check data is being received ok

Comment: Since `console.log(data)` shows the page2 response, the `echo $data1` clearly must have gotten through. Try to debug a bit further / and reexplain what issue you see.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want session with that.

Update `page2.php`. Try:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['myDat'] = isset($_SESSION['myDat']) ? $_SESSION['myDat'] : "";
    $_SESSION['myDat'] = isset($_POST['myDat'])?$_POST['myDat']:$_SESSION['myDat'];
    echo $_SESSION['myDat'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please in page2.php page

try to print

```
 $data1 = isset($_POST['myDat'])? $_POST['myDat']: "";

 echo $data1;
```

it will help you .... :)

Comment: I have also tried, <?php
                
                $data1 = $_POST['myDat'];
                
                echo $data1;
                ?> Still, its not working

Comment: so you have tried to print out $_POST array still not getting any result than it might be problem with your ajax call please open up  console and  > go to network  and try to make ajax call and check it will post myDat varible or not

Comment: Hi. I can get the variable "myDat" printed in the console in page1.php. But I cannot receive it in page2.php using the php code

Comment: When I load page2.php, it doesn't display the variable.